# Python 3 unittest cannot mock method used inside functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying unit test in Python.

**test.py**

```
from unittest import TestCase,main
from unittest.mock import patch

import file

def mock_return(*args):
    return -1

class Tests(TestCase):
    @patch("file.Foo.a", side_effect=mock_return)
    def test_1(self, mock_fun):
        self.assertEqual(file.Foo().a(), -1)

    @patch("os.urandom", side_effect=mock_return)
    def test_2(self, mock_fun):
        self.assertEqual(file.Foo().b(), -1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**file.py**

```
from os import urandom

class Foo:
    def a(self):
        return 1

    def b(self):
        return urandom(1)
```

Why `test_1` passed but `test_2` failed? Is there a way to mock a method used by other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must patch the binding used by the function being tested.

```
from os import urandom  # in file.py
```

binds name `urandom` to the function `os.urandom` *in* the `file` module.  `Foo.b` accesses the function via the `file.urandom` binding.  So the test for `Foo.b` must patch `file.urandom`, not `os.urandom`.

Comment: This is the answer I need. `from os import urandom` needs `file.urandom` and `import os` need `os.urandom`

Comment: I was thinking of changing `@patch("os.urandom",...` to `@patch("file.urandom",...`, and both test pass after that.  An alternative is to change `from os import urandom` to `import os` and change the call in `Foo.b` to `os.urandom`.  I personally prefer the former as I prefer doing the patching in the tested code, rather than the stdlib.  But the important point is that the test, including mocking, must carefully match the tested code.